# Locally uniformly convex Banach space, which is not uniformly convex.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I would like to find an example of a reflexive Banach space $X$, which is locally uniformly convex, however, it is not uniformly convex.

The motivation is that I am studying degree theory for operators $T:X\to X^\star$, which satisfies the $S_+$ condition and in some point, it is assumed that $X$ can be renormed in such a way that the new norm is equivalent to the old one and both $X,X^\star$ are locally uniformly convex (Lindenstrauss-Asplund-Trojanski theorem).

It seems that the example is totally non-trivial. Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the space [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gz04Rv8G3OcC&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false) is reflexive.

Comment: After you posted your comment @DavidMitra, I was wondering. Does locally uniformly convex implies reflexivity?

Comment: The same link states a result of Day: If $X$ is a separable Banach space, there is an equivalent norm which is locally uniformly convex and such that $X^*$ with the dual norm is strictly convex.